# ASP.NET Allow + Symbol in email validation expression

Tags: asp.net, validation

Hey I have the follow email validation expression

^[\w-.]+@([\w-]+.)+[\w-]{2,4}$

What I am looking for is for email addresses to be allowed which have a "+" before the @ part of the email cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use a full [RFC 822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc822.html) regex

```
^((?>[a-zA-Z\d!#$%&'*+\-/=?^_`{|}~]+\x20*|"((?=[\x01-\x7f])[^"\\]|\\[\x01-\x7f])*"\x20*)*(?<angle><))?((?!\.)(?>\.?[a-zA-Z\d!#$%&'*+\-/=?^_`{|}~]+)+|"((?=[\x01-\x7f])[^"\\]|\\[\x01-\x7f])*")@(((?!-)[a-zA-Z\d\-]+(?<!-)\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}|\[(((?(?<!\[)\.)(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d?\d)){4}|[a-zA-Z\d\-]*[a-zA-Z\d]:((?=[\x01-\x7f])[^\\\[\]]|\\[\x01-\x7f])+)\])(?(angle)>)$
```

And the [RegexLib](http://regexlib.com) is great place for finding regex for most requirements, you are rarely the first to want to do something.

Answer (score 1):

Just change it to `^[\w-.]+(?:\+[\w]*)?@([\w-]+.)+[\w-]{2,4}$`

This allows for + before @ and some characters which is optional. 
So
aliostad@gmail.com
aliostad+ali@gmail.com are both valid.

Updated.

Comment: Great thanks 1 more Question for this phonenumber validator how can I allow i.e "(" or ")" or "+" or "-"

Comment: atm for phonenumbers I have ^[+\d ]+$

Comment: Stevie, can you ask the question with a bit more info? Similar to this question which you gave good examples.

Comment: Yeah I would like to allow a phone number such as +00(49) 87956325412 at the moment my validation only allows numbers ^[+\d ]+$

Comment: Try this: ^\+?\(001\)|(00\(\d\d)\)\s*\d{8,12}$

Comment: No didnt seem to like the "("

Comment: Make sure you have no space after the telephone. I am using Expresso and your example works,.

Comment: <code><asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" 
                        ValidationExpression="^\+?(001)|(00(\d\d))\s*\d{8,12}$" 
                        ControlToValidate="txtPhone" 
                        Display="None" 
                        EnableClientScript="false"
                        ErrorMessage="Please provide valid phone number.">
                   </asp:RegularExpressionValidator></code> and phone number +00(49) 87956325412. And it fails the validator i.e it thinks it is an invalid number

Comment: Use Expresso http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm and see if it works in there. If so, make a new question and put the link here so that I can check it up.